# Datalist get selected item value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a database which contains a table named Quiz, and has the columns [QuizID, Name, Level]. I am filling a `DataList` using the EF wizard with data from the database.

I need to get the Quiz ID (Primary key) of the item that I click on in the `DataList` so that I can pass it to stored procedures. How do I get the ID in the click event?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
    {
        string ID = Session["ID"].ToString();
        var level = (from tbl in db.CheckLevel(ID) select tbl).FirstOrDefault();
        var quizLevel = ??
    }
}
```

Comment: How would we know? What is quiz level?

Comment: It's an item in the Quiz Table.

Comment: You need to provide some kind of details about what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I have a database, It contains table name Quiz has columns [QuizID, Name, Level] the Datalist filled with EF wizard, I need to get the Quiz ID of the item I click on. [I added a button of take quiz I need to check on ID where only visible items are Quiz Name and Button]

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar situation to this. And I managed to solve my problem by storing the ID to hidden field in item template. Then using the value of the hidden field as the ID to select the item in DataSet pulled from the database. I hope this helps.